# Getting error while integrating GA4 via Segment

Tags: firebase, segment, google-analytics-4

I am trying to integrate GA4 via segment, in which no internal implementation would be required on the app side. Since segment has all the data, I can directly make the destination and link that destination to segment.

Hello All, I am trying to setup GA4 via segment (the CDP platform) and am facing some challenges. The first one is in Firebase. As I can see, Google Analytics is added to our Firebase, but I am unable to change or create other properties there. I went through documents and all, but it is still of no use.
Segment link: https://app.segment.com
Document followed: https://segment.com/docs/connections/destinations/catalog/actions-google-analytics-4/#custom-event
[enter image description here.] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzeHP.png)

I am not able to sure about it that integration is done successfully or not because unable to check data on ga4 realtime.
Seeking help here. have anybody done this integration before or someone can help me with the freelancer who can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.